# NSMutableURLRequest setHTTPShouldHandleCookies

Tags: ios, nsmutableurlrequest

I am working with xcode 5.1.1 for Logic unit testing for my iOS project

For the below code, the `NSLog` output is "Handles cookies NO" both the times:

```
NSMutableURLRequest *newReq = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
NSLog(@"Handles cookies %@", [newReq HTTPShouldHandleCookies]? @"YES":@"NO");
[newReq setHTTPShouldHandleCookies:YES];
NSLog(@"Handles cookies %@", [newReq HTTPShouldHandleCookies]? @"YES":@"NO");
```

Output:

```
2014-05-25 19:41:03.045 xctest[2097:303] Handles cookies NO
2014-05-25 19:41:05.983 xctest[2097:303] Handles cookies NO
```

What am I doing wrong. My test is failing due to this value not being set properly. I am quite sure the same test was passing last time around, and so `setHTTPShouldHandleCookie` would actually set the value to YES. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should initialize the request with a URL; a request without a URL isn't a useful request. The default value for `HTTPShouldHandleCookies` is `YES`, so calling `setHTTPShouldHandleCookies:YES` should be unnecessary for a valid request. One has to conclude, then, that you don't have a valid request in the first place.

Comment: Thanks. Setting a URL made it work. This should've been documented in the API docs. Wonder why it isn't. Whether initializing it with no url is useful should be left to the program logic. All other methods like setHTTPMethod, setTimeoutInterval do work without setting a correct url

Comment: HIt's documented after a fashion. `-initWithURL:cachePolicy:timeoutInterval:` is documented as the designated initializer for `NSURLRequest`, which is the superclass for `NSMutableURLRequest`. So it doesn't seem like calling '-init` to initialize a mutable request is a good plan. I expect the issue has less to do with setting an URL than it does just calling the designated initializer. You could try calling `-initWithURL:` and passing in `nil` for the URL -- I bet that'd work.

Comment: Yes indeed, it does work with setting the URL nil. I was trying to test a method that sets common attributes, headers etc on a url request, was not interested in the url itself, so missed it. Thanks